# Can I create cross lined background box with pure css

Tags: html, css, background

[image]

I want to create band for my widget title as above image and HTML structure like this;

```
<div class="wt">
    <div class="blue-area">text</div>
    <div class="green-area">text</div>
</div>
```

Text length changeable , so may vary blue area width like this;

[image]

Can I create this with pure css?

Comment: http://www.css3shapes.com/ Play with it, it is always a better feeling if you can do it yourself ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a fair bit of CSS here, but I think it's what you're looking for. I've achieved the look of an arrow by the use of the `::after` pseudo element

I've also had to make the `<div>`s a fixed height, due to not being able to size the triangle relatively. Go ahead, change the text and watch the `<div>`s change appropriately.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd998/1/)

```css
.blue-area,
.green-area {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.blue-area {
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  background-color: #26799b;
  position: relative;
}

.blue-area:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent #26799b transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 30px 30px 0;
  display: block;
}

.green-area {
  background-color: #386c19;
  padding: 0 8px 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wt">
  <div class="blue-area">text dfg gh fgh </div><div class="green-area">text fgh fgh fgh fgdfg dfg dfg</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, with background gradient:
exemple:

```
div {background:linear-gradient(to top right, #247A9B, #247A9B 50%,#386C19 50% ,#386C19);}
```

for older browser you will need prefix.

demo on html : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xFjEl

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient( to top right, #247A9B, #247A9B 49%, #386C19 50%, #386C19);
  min-height: 100%;
}


/* or use degrees */

p {
  margin: 2em;
  background: #247A9B;
  border: solid;
}

p span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1.5em 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient( 60deg, #386C19, #386C19 93%, #247A9B 94%, #247A9B);
}

p span b {
  display: none;
}

p span:hover b {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span> text to increase on hover <b>here more text in green area</b></span> text in blue area
</p>
```

Comment: How does this accommodate changing text?: *'Text length changeable , so may vary blue area width'*

Comment: oh, i did not pay attention to that part, the idea is the same, increase % of where you have the line within the first element, the second element will only need a plain background-color

Comment: here you have the green area growing according to text-lenght , codepen updated (hover the green area to show more text )